# Minion "not connected" vs. "not responding"

Tags: salt-stack

Some of my minions are not responsive, for various reasons. They respond, however, in different ways:

```
sent222:
    Minion did not return. [No response]
sent036:
    Minion did not return. [Not connected]
```

**What is the difference between `No response` and `Not connected`?**

I ran a `tcpdump` against both of these hosts, but there is no communication. I believe that this is expected because the master waits for the minion to connect - thus the surprising difference in the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of salt-internal question.

Simplifying:

`Not connected`:
If the minion is known to salt-master e.g. you can see minion under:`salt-run cache.list minions` and the minion process is down

`No response`:
If the minion is not known to salt-master

The definition of *known to salt-master* is interesting.
You can have minions that were connected. Thus you think that they will appear as `Not connected` but from different reasons when they are be wiped from salt-master cache - you will see them as `No response`

In general, [the Github Issues for SaltStack](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/) is the best place for salt related questions

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Two comments: "*Kind of salt-internal question*" - well this is the user-exposed error message and sine there are two distinct ones I thought that the difference between them was relevant."*[the github repo] is the best place for salt related questions*" - this is good to know, I usually avoid using the `issues` to ask questions, but here it is indeed the best channel as it invites questions.

Comment: This said - how can the minion **not** be known to the salt master and still be requested by that salt master (via `'*'`)?

Comment: IMHO `Not connected` or `No response` comes from technical internals and I don't think user should care about this. About "not be known" - when (somehow) salt-master will wipe its own minion cache (and minion still be visible under `salt-key -L`) then `'*'` will reference him. Yes, use GH issues, mind to use "question" template